# Private messaging in RabbitMQ. What to choose: Validated User-ID, queue-per-client, vhost-per-client?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm building a system which delivers private message to dynamic number of consumers.  The consumer subscribes to the queue using their own username/password and waits for messages (the consumers can send message as well). The message includes sensitive informations.

The thing is, how to ensure (in a secure way) that the message sent by publisher to "consumers1" will be received only by "consumers1". I've done some research:

1. [Validated User-ID](https://www.rabbitmq.com/validated-user-id.html) + VPN
2. write-queue-per-client and send-queue-per-client
3. vhost-per-client (with 2 queues)

Which method is the most safety? Is the VPN a good replacement to TLS/SSL in Option 1? Option 1 seems to be the simplest in implementation and maintenance, but is it secure enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1. Validated User ID provides limited authentication of the client that publishes messages. Is this your case? Or are the clients the consumers? If they are only consumers then I don't see that validated user Id helps. The VPN prevents a man in the middle from sniffing your clients credentials which I suppose is a good substitute for TLS.

Option 2, combined with appropriate permissions for each client (read permission which names the queues the client should be restricted to) will prevent other one client from reading the messages of another client.

Option 3, is like option 2 but even stronger as a virtual host acts as a security boundary so even if permissions are not set correctly, one client cannot read the messages of another client.

Also consider a security breach at your organisation. Messages with sensitive data will be sitting unencrypted in your RabbitMQ cluster. You may wish to encrypt the message bodies also, though this increases complexity considerably.

If it was my system and I really cared about client isolation and protection of client data I would at a minimum:

- use TLS to protect credentials and data over the internet (client to RabbitMQ)
- mandate the use of the user id header
- Put each client in a separate vhost

Then depending on how practical it would be (and how paranoid I am):

- Encrypt message content if possible. How you share symmetric keys, or use public/private encryption could be tricky.
- If practical, I might also consider using Client Certificates to authenticate clients instead of plain user/pass authentication. This would require the use of TLS as I believe you cannot activate client certificate authentication without server TLS authentication also.
  https://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyabecker/Using-SSL-client-certificates-for-authentication-with-RabbitMQ

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think that separate vhosts are the solution :-) They add some extra complexity in gathering messages from consumers (rabbitmq client can't subscribe to different vhosts using one connection) but that is the price for the isolation.